# Spell-check and autocorrect only working in English

Tags: macos, language, spellcheck, autocorrect

I can't manage to get the in-line spell check or autocorrect to work in any apps. In particular this is frustrating with my e-mail, as this is the biggest part of my job and I frequently need to switch languages.

I have gone through the settings for turning on autocorrect and I've been sure to turn on the settings in each app under the Edit menu (which is usually on already). Unfortunately, for example in Dutch, it simply refuses to work, although it *has* worked in the past.

Strangely, it *does* recognize that I'm not typing in English anymore, as it stops underlining Dutch words as misspelled, but does *not* proceed to underline misspelled Dutch words. As soon as I start typing in English, it checks spelling again.

I'm not sure what changed in the meantime. A few minor OSX updates might be the culprit or the only other cause I can come up with might be that CleanMyMac cleaned too vigorously and deleted languages and settings - although I'm very careful about that. (If the latter is the case, how would I go about checking this and restoring them?)

[image]

I'm running OSX 10.10.4 on a 2013 11-inch Macbook Air.

Thanks in advance!